# My physical Android device is not detected by android studio to test my Android Apps

Tags: android, android-studio

I am using android studio 2.1. And I am connecting my device to my computer then I am trying to run my application. When I am clicking run button, then one window is opened the window named Select Deployment Target. The window have two sections Connected devices and Available Emulators. But in connected device section my device is not shown. And in my device the developer mode is already on and in my SDK I am already installed the Google USB Driver. My system configuration is
Asus X54C
OS:Windows 10 64 bit
HDD:500 GB
RAM:2 GB
Please help me to find the problem.

Comment: 1.install usb driver in your system 2.enable MTP in usb option and enable Usb debugging in developer mode

Comment: When you plug your device in ,can you search its folders?

Answer (score 0):

Run command "adb devices", are you sure your device has been displayed on the list?

Or you can even try to run your app over wifi, article: https://davidng94.wordpress.com/2016/06/21/debugging-android-application-via-a-wireless-connection/

Comment: Yeah, press Windowlogo key + R, type "cmd" and then run "adb devices" :)

Answer (score 0):

check you link cable and open Developer Mode

Answer (score 0):

Connect your device and run

```
adb devices
```

with similar output:

```
List of devices attached
3438e1ce1200        device
```

If your device is really connected your will see the list of attached devices.
If nothing appears maybe you have to pairs your device with the computer or maybe, you have to enable **usb debugging**  from *Settings > Developer Options > USB debugging*.

Also check the device drivers on your pc.

Byeee.